# How to call designated superclass initializers in Swift

Tags: objective-c, uiview, swift

In Objective-C there is this standard pattern in initializers to call the designated initializer of the superclass.

For example:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}
```

What is the standard way to do the same initialization in a Swift class?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this

```
init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    // Initialization code
}
```